# Swift UIViewReportBrokenSuperviewChain cause by Layer manipulation

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10

I run into a problem after migrating my code to Swift 3.
I guess iOS10 raises new issues now and it's actually not related to Swift itself.

The error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'View has lost track of its superview, most likely through unsupported use of CALayer API on the view's layer. If this isn't a crash yet, it will be in the near future. 
    Problem view: <UIToolbar: 0x102552d80; frame = (0 0; 375 683); alpha = 0.97; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x1700383e0>>
    Expected parent: <MyModelView: 0x10250ecd0; frame = (0 -16; 375 683); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x17003d4a0>>
Break on UIViewReportBrokenSuperviewChain to debug.'
```

The code triggering the issue is :

```
[c presentViewController:tabBarViewController animated:NO completion:^{
```

The sub code responsible for the problem seems to be:

```
- (void)addBlurView
{
  CGRect viewBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen]applicationFrame];
  self.myModelView = [[MyModalView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(viewBounds.origin.x, -16, viewBounds.size.width, viewBounds.size.height+36)];

  if(![self toolbar]) {
    _toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:[self.myModelView bounds]];
    [_toolbar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
    _toolbar.alpha = 0.97;
    [self.myModelView.layer insertSublayer:_toolbar.layer atIndex:0];
  }

  [self.view addSubview:self.myModelView];
}
```

Comment: Why are you manipulating a layer hierarchy? Maybe it's better to add a toolbar just as a subview of myModelView and get rid of this problem for sure?

Comment: Well, it s legacy code so I m just trying to fix the issue here. For now I just removed the insertSublayer issue. I found that It was some kind of trick to get transparency background. Apparently it's a known trick but that makes the app crash in the new one. I ll update this post as soon as I finish with it.

Comment: Hi @Mikael "Break on UIViewReportBrokenSuperviewChain to debug.". Do you know what this mean? I got this error also and it's not well documented.

Comment: Well, in this case, I was trying to insert an UIView element to another one. But the first element was not added to the UIViewController.view therefore, it triggers an error.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had this issue with a library when moving over to Xcode 8 (Material-Controls-For-iOS - MDTextField). I found that the problem was coming from where the layer of one view (which had no superview) was being added to another.

It looks like this may be the case for yourself also - your toolbar being created has not been added to a superview first. The fix I used was to add the view as a subview of the view that the layer was being added to, so in your case adding the toolbar as a subview of myModelView should stop the error.

Comment: You clearly found the reason of the crash here. if I add: [self.myModelView addSubview:_toolbar]; before inserting the layer, no crash.