# Crash while presenting a new VC modally in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios10

I am facing a weird crash issue with iOS 10; iOS 9 works good. While presenting camera view controller modally from current view controller, it crashes.

This is the line of code that is crashing:

```
- (void)searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar {
    if (self.searchBar.isFirstResponder) {
        [self.searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    }

    if (self.searchOverlay) {
        [self.searchOverlay removeView];
        self.searchOverlay = nil;
    }

    MyCameraScannerViewController *aCameraScannerViewController = [[MyCameraScannerViewController alloc] initWithScanningMessage:@"Please point camera on barcode"];
    aCameraScannerViewController.delegate = self;
    aCameraScannerViewController.showTargetReticle = YES;

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:aCameraScannerViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

I am getting crash with following error:

```
2016-10-28 12:22:35.494135 MyApp[27308:8137793] *** Assertion failure in void UIViewReportBrokenSuperviewChain(UIView *__strong, UIView *__strong, BOOL)(), /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit/UIKit-3599.6.1/UIView.m:190
```

Anyone has any idea about this crash?

Comment: Can you add whole code of this class?

Comment: @KeyurHirani Added the complete method.

Answer (score 1):

You've got this error because one UI item you are handling its layer is not attached to the view tree.

For exemple (its in Swift) if you have something like this:

```
      layer.addSublayer(start.layer)
```

You must be absolutely sure the UI element start is already in the view hierarchy as follows:

```
      addSubview(start)
```

So look into the code of MyCameraScannerViewController for views with layer manipulation and add all the required addSubview().

Comment: This fixed my issue. Do you know why you can't add a view's layer to a subview's layer? This works on the device but crashes in the simulator when I try to run it. Do you have any links you can share to expound on this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are calling `presentViewController` from a background thread. All UI activity has to happen on the main thread.

Do your UI updates like:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [navigationController presentViewController:cameraViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

});
```

Comment: @Abhinav can you update your question with more code?

Comment: I have added the entire method.

Answer (score 0):

As per the crash error you posted says `UIViewReportBrokenSuperviewChain` . This means the problem is with adding a layer of View1 on View2 (where View1 does not have any superview)

Please post more code to identify the problem more clearly

Comment: Thanks @Sharpkits. I have added the complete method.

Comment: @Abhinav I could not get much from the code you update..but seems self.searchOverlay is a problem. Checkout the this link, you may find the solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565424/swift-uiviewreportbrokensuperviewchain-cause-by-layer-manipulation

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code and check:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                [navigationController presentViewController:cameraViewController animated:YES completion:nil];

            });

    });
```