# UIKit UIViewReportBrokenSuperviewChain exception

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

It has become really difficult to catch this issue. I have never got it when I am running the app from Xcode. But on testing this comes **sometimes** (not saying it would never come on running). I integrated [**Fabric crash analytics**](https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install) for getting the where about of the exception. But all I could know is :

> Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException 0  CoreFoundation
>   0x1842ee1c0 **exceptionPreprocess 1  libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x182d2855c objc_exception_throw 2  CoreFoundation
>
>   0x1842ee094 +[NSException raise:format:] 3  Foundation
>
>   0x184d7b808 -[NSAssertionHandler
>   handleFailureInFunction:file:lineNumber:description:] 4  UIKit
>
>   0x18a428d7c UIViewReportBrokenSuperviewChain 5  UIKit
>
>   0x18a429438 _UIViewTopDownSubtreeTraversal 6  UIKit
>
>   0x18aa9f12c -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout_EngineDelegate)
>   _invalidateSystemLayoutSizeFittingSizeAtEngineDelegateLevel] 7  Foundation                     0x184d2021c -[NSISEngine
>   tryToAddConstraintWithMarker:expression:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
>   8  Foundation                     0x184d1fd3c -[NSLayoutConstraint
>   _addLoweredExpression:toEngine:integralizationAdjustment:lastLoweredConstantWasRounded:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:]
>   9  Foundation                     0x184d1d950 -[NSLayoutConstraint
>   _addToEngine:integralizationAdjustment:mutuallyExclusiveConstraints:] 10 UIKit                          0x18a248cb0
>   __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 11 Foundation                     0x184d1d480 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] 12 UIKit
>   0x18a248abc __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
>   _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke 13 UIKit                          0x18a1452b4 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]
>   14 UIKit                          0x18a248be8
>   __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 15 Foundation                     0x184d1d480 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] 16 UIKit
>   0x18a248abc __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
>   _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke 17 UIKit                          0x18a1452b4 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]
>   18 UIKit                          0x18a248be8
>   __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke_2 19 Foundation                     0x184d1d480 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] 20 UIKit
>   0x18a248abc __57-[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport)
>   _switchToLayoutEngine:]_block_invoke 21 UIKit                          0x18a1452b4 -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _switchToLayoutEngine:]
>   22 UIKit                          0x18a2868ac
>   -[UIView(AdditionalLayoutSupport) _initializeHostedLayoutEngine] 23 UIKit                          0x18a2505e4
>   -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutEngine_windowDidChange] 24 UIKit                          0x18a1453b0 -[UIView(Internal)
>   _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] 25 UIKit                          0x18a144a64 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy)
>   _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke 26 Foundation                     0x184d1d480 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] 27 UIKit
>   0x18a1448d8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] 28 UIKit
>
>   0x18a1507a4 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] 29
>   UIKit                          0x18a150090 -[UIView(Hierarchy)
>   addSubview:] 30 UIKit                          0x18a32d428
>   -[_UIParallaxDimmingView didMoveToWindow] 31 UIKit                          0x18a1458f0 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] 32 UIKit 
>   0x18a1455b8 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] 33 UIKit 
>   0x18a144a64 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy)
>   _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke 34 Foundation                     0x184d1d480 -[NSISEngine withBehaviors:performModifications:] 35 UIKit
>   0x18a1448d8 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] 36 UIKit
>
>   0x18a1507a4 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] 37
>   UIKit                          0x18a150090 -[UIView(Hierarchy)
>   addSubview:] 38 UIKit                          0x18a3c021c
>   __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:]_block_invoke_2 39 UIKit
>
>   0x18a156f68 +[UIView(Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] 40 UIKit
>
>   0x18a32cf48 __53-[_UINavigationParallaxTransition
>   animateTransition:]_block_invoke 41 UIKit
>
>   0x18a448f74 +[UIView(Internal)
>   _performBlockDelayingTriggeringResponderEvents:] 42 UIKit                          0x18a32ca88 -[_UINavigationParallaxTransition animateTransition:] 43
>   UIKit                          0x18a2e9ba8 -[UINavigationController
>   _startCustomTransition:] 44 UIKit                          0x18a201858 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] 45 UIKit                          0x18a2014c0 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] 46
>   UIKit                          0x18a201424 -[UILayoutContainerView
>   layoutSubviews] 47 UIKit                          0x18a146220
>   -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] 48 QuartzCore                     0x187606188 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] 49 QuartzCore
>
>   0x1875fae64 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) 50
>   QuartzCore                     0x1875fad24
>   CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) 51
>   QuartzCore                     0x1875777ec
>   CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) 52 QuartzCore
>
>   0x18759ec58 CA::Transaction::commit() 53 QuartzCore
>
>   0x18759f678 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*,
>   unsigned long, void*) 54 CoreFoundation                 0x18429b7dc
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** 55 CoreFoundation                 0x18429940c __CFRunLoopDoObservers 56
>   CoreFoundation                 0x18429989c __CFRunLoopRun 57
>   CoreFoundation                 0x1841c8048 CFRunLoopRunSpecific 58
>   GraphicsServices               0x185c4e198 GSEventRunModal 59 UIKit
>   0x18a1b42fc -[UIApplication _run] 60 UIKit
>   0x18a1af034 UIApplicationMain 61 Truegroups
>   0x1001e1b94 main (main.m:14) 62 libdispatch.dylib
>   0x1831ac5b8 (Missing)

With the heading as **UIKit UIViewReportBrokenSuperviewChain**

I am wondering how to catch this issue.

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39565424/swift-uiviewreportbrokensuperviewchain-cause-by-layer-manipulation ?